# PHP How to make IF based on $ret value

Tags: php, forms, if-statement

I have a form in PHP and if user put correct coupon code something like that is defined:

```
$ret['status'] = 'success';
```

and next is:

```
if( $ret['status'] == 'success' ){
                        $ret['coupon-id'] = $query->post_id;
                        $ret['amount'] = $post_option['coupon-discount-amount'];
                        $ret['type'] = $post_option['coupon-discount-type'];



                        $discount_text = '';
                        if( $ret['type'] == 'percent' ){
                            $discount_text =  $post_option['coupon-discount-amount'] . '%';

                        }else{
                            $discount_text = gdlr_lms_money_format($post_option['coupon-discount-amount']);
                        }
                        $ret['message'] = sprintf(__('You got %s discount', 'gdlr-lms'), $discount_text);                           
                    }
```

And the bottom of the form there is submit button with this conditions:

```
if( empty($_POST['first_name']) || empty($_POST['last_name']) || empty($_POST['email']) ){
                $ret['status'] = 'failed';
                $ret['message'] = __('Please fill all required fields.', 'gdlr-lms');
```

I need to add to this condition that correct coupon is also required. What I need to add to this code to have it done? I have been looking for answers for 5 hours and I tried everything what I have found but nothing work - please help me! :)

This is the website with form - after registration form there will be the entry form to the course I am ask about.

http://semcamp.university/course/starting-company-all-you-need-to-know-to-start-company-2-2-2-2/

You can login in using username: stackoverflow and password: stack1 and valid copuon code is 1234 or test1

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear about in which if statement should the coupon be validated. But, supposing that it needs to be validated in the last one (the if for the submit button), you could do it that way:

```
if( empty($_POST['first_name']) || empty($_POST['last_name']) || empty($_POST['email']) ){
    $ret['status'] = 'failed';
    $ret['message'] = __('Please fill all required fields.', 'gdlr-lms');
}
elseif( $ret['status'] != 'success') {
    $ret['status'] = 'failed';
    $ret['message'] = __('Please provide a valid coupon.', 'gdlr-lms');
}
```

Comment: Thank You, but taht doesn't work. To be more clear this is the website for validation: [http://semcamp.university/course/starting-company-all-you-need-to-know-to-start-company-2-2-2-2/ ] and I don't know hot to share hole code with You? But now it looks like it doesnt know if there is `$ret['status] = 'sucecess'`

Comment: You can login in using username: stackoverflow and password: stack1 and valid copun is 1234 or test1